# Coffeescript extend class without overwriting or having to call 'super'

Tags: coffeescript

Something that's been bugging me and I'm probably being stupid, but here's my issue:

```
class GenericModel extends Backbone.Model
  initialize: () ->
    console.log 'one'

class SpecificModel extends GenericModel
  initialize: () ->
    console.log 'two'
```

I want it to say "one two", but instead it just says "two", which is expected as the initialize method is being overwritten. Obviously I can make SpecificModel call `super` as the first line of initialize, but that can get pretty ugly, tiresome (and I often forget to do it) when extending the class with many many many other classes all over the codebase. In my real world case, I have lots of generic event bindings on the generic model, and then specific operative code on the models that extend it, and I would rather not have to call super on them all, as it just makes it hard to track when the bindings aren't being... bound.

Is there a way of getting all methods that inherit from class extension to **automatically call super** on their parent?

Thanks

Comment: Ps, renaming `initialize` in my specific models to something else, then calling that function from the parent class' initialize is not desired either

Comment: No, that's not how inheritance works. If you ***override*** a method, you are also responsible for calling the original *overridden* method if that is what you want. A different approach might be in order, e.g., an actual event system which can register multiple listeners per event.

Comment: Ah that's annoying, but I kinda suspected that. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Two ways in coffeescript

use coffeescript super shortcut (see http://coffeescript.org/#classes )

```
class GenericModel extends Backbone.Model
  initialize:() ->
    console.log 'one'
class SpecificModel extends GenericModel
  initialize:() ->
    super()
    console.log 'two'
```

or directly call on overridden method via prototype

```
class GenericModel extends Backbone.Model
  initialize:() ->
    console.log 'one'
class SpecificModel extends GenericModel
  initialize:() ->
    GenericModel::initialize.call(@,arguments)
    console.log 'two'
```

Comment: I said in my question that I wanted a way that didn't require calling anything within the `SpecificModel`'s initialize method. (and in the question title)

Comment: If then, you need a more elaborate system like backbone constructor>initialize method or that of marionette via subInitialize method definition or initialization event to register to.

Comment: I am actually using Marionette. What's this subInitialize you speak of? Ta

Comment: marionette adds extra empty methods for you to inherit without overriding methods such as render or show (onRender, onShow) + it triggers events if one wants to add extra work. Here, you would do the same, in GenericModel::initialize, you would call for a this.onInitialize?(options), then sub classes could implement onInitialize instead of initialize. It will work if you do not go too deep in inheritance.

Comment: Ah yes I know about that, and there is no `onInitialize` provided as default. But as I also said in a comment to my question, I don't want to go around renaming every single initialize in my code to onInitialize, and it's a short term solution as it doesn't allow deep inheritance as you mention.

Comment: Then I do not see other solution than rewriting the extend method in order to integrate automatically the super method call.